# How do I migrate my Stack Overflow question to Server Fault?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

How do I migrate my question from Stack Overflow to Server Fault?

I searched how to migrate in Meta Stack Overflow, but I didn't absorb how to do it.

Comment: You can't do it yourself. Flag the question, choose Other and explain why it should be migrated.

Comment: Users will flag the question, AFAIK.

Comment: @Glenn-- not really, [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18761565/447356) is already closed and users (even high rep) can't migrate to Server Fault themselves. Only a moderator can do that.

Comment: understood....!

Answer (score 3):

Update: Looks like the question in question is a bit too localized. [Please don't flag for migration.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761565/how-to-find-the-ip-address-and-port-number-for-sqlserver-2008-to-connect-databas#comment27763251_18761565)

---

Flag the question for moderator attention with the "other" option and ask for migration to Server Fault.

[image]

Make sure you know that it is [on topic](https://serverfault.com/about) for them. Server Fault expects questions to be at the professional level, so not all such questions are on topic there.